# Order made with PayPal, new order e-mail not sent

Tags: orders, paypal, ce-1.7.0.2, email

I have a problem with the orders with PayPal payment gateway. When order is made, the customer didn't receive any email for "New Order" placed.

I have established a sandbox for my PayPal and changed the IPN settings in my PayPal account, but nothing seems to make this work.
I am working on Magento 1.7.0.2 and I have setup multi shop magento system.

Please provide me solution of this problem if anyone have solution

Comment: got the same issue. any ideas? thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try this: Under System->Configuration->Payment Methods->PayPal Payments Standard->Advanced Setting turn "Enable SSL verification" to No and save. Everything should now work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set Payment Action as **sale** so that paypal will process order and send ipn request automatically.Checkout this [article](http://blog.ecommercesoftwaresolutionsonline.com/archives/366/paypal-online-payment-action-sale-authorization.html) for more details

Comment: Rohit S, thx for your response.
Payment Action is set to "Sale" and "Order Item Status to enable Downloads" to "Invoiced".

Comment: Did it solve the problem

Comment: Unfortunately not:|

Comment: I suggest you to enable paypal logs (System->configuration->paypal->Website Payments Standard settings->Debug->yes) and check if any error messages are logged.

Comment: In my payment_paypal_standard.log I only get Array with the parameters of the request. And there everything seems to be ok. No errors.

Comment: You can find IPN history from Paypal Admin Interface.Check this link http://eventespresso.com/forums/2011/03/checking-paypal-ipn-history/. Check whether the IPN messages are delivered to magento.Also make sure there are no firewalls blocking IPN requests.

Comment: There are no IPN messages to be seen in my PayPal Backend. I will check all setting again and I hope I can get it to work.
Thank you for all your help.

Comment: From the Bug reporting on http://www.magentocommerce.com/ is evident that this is a know bug. I will wait for the new version of Magento, where hopefully this will no longer be an issue.

Comment: @knospe What's the actual URL for the bug? Thanks